# How to route one video device to multiple programs

Tags: linux, video, devices, vlc, video-encoding

I'd like to direct the output of a single capture card (Hauppauge PVR-150) to two programs: VLC (for streaming on LAN) and MythTV for scheduled recording. I think it's possible to do this with the V4L2loopback device, but I'm not sure how.

Example of what I want to accomplish:

If these are the pertinent devices:

```
/dev/video0   #PVR-150 baseband source
/dev/video1   #v4l2loopback sink 1
/dev/video2   #v4l2loopback source 1
/dev/video3   #v4l2loopback sink 2
/dev/video4   #v4l2loopback source 2
```

On boot, I want to direct /dev/video0 to /dev/video1 and /dev/video3. Then I would direct VLC to encode from /dev/video2 and MythTV to record from /dev/video4.

Can this work? If so, how can I set it up to run every time the machine boots?